# Avoid double-move when returning a pair in C++

Tags: c++, tuples, move-constructor

I'm trying to write a function that returns a pair of objects, one of which is harder to construct than the other. This code comes close to illustrating what I'm trying:

```C++
#include<iostream>
#include<tuple>

using namespace std;

struct A {
  int i;
  A(A&& a): i(a.i) { cout << "move-constructing A: "<<a.i<<"\n"; }
  A(int j): i(j) { cout << "int-constructing A: "<<j<<"\n"; }
};
using APair = pair<A,A>;

APair get_As() {
  A a(8);
  return {piecewise_construct, make_tuple(move(a)), make_tuple(10)};
}

int main()
{
  APair As = get_As();
  return 0;
}
```

But, when I run this, I see a double move of the `A` constructed with `8`:

```
int-constructing A: 8
move-constructing A: 8
move-constructing A: 8
int-constructing A: 10
```

I recon that's because the `A` is moved into the `std::tuple` and then into the `APair` of `main()`. Clearly, a single move should be sufficient to construct the `APair`, but I cannot see how I would do that, since the piecewise constructor seems unavoidable, which means I also have to provide a tuple... My question is thus: how can this be done with a single move of `A`?

Comment: I may have to specify that the construction of `a` is oversimplified in the example. It's actually quite a process, including the need to manipulate an already constructed version.

Comment: Is there a problem with `return {move(a), 10};` ?  If you can update the question to show code where that behaves worse than expected, that would be good

Comment: ooh, you're using the `(U1&&, U2&&)`-constructor, that should work too. Good thinking! I think this starts to break when the constructor of `A` takes more than one argument though...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might use [`std::forward_as_tuple`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/forward_as_tuple) to avoid extra move constructor:

```
return {piecewise_construct, std::forward_as_tuple(move(a)), make_tuple(10)};
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c0cd8f210c8f42d7)

So you have `std::tuple<A&&>` instead of `std::tuple<A>` (which move construct).